# Trying to convert existing function using Linq and lambda gives compile time error

Tags: c#

I have code as :

```
            var multiDoc = XDocument.Load(transactionXML);
            var childElements = multiDoc.Descendants("Transaction");
            List<Document> doclist = new List<Document>();
            List<Document> docEntireList = new List<Document>();
            foreach (var child in childElements)
            {
                string childTransaction = child.ToString();
                var childDoc = new XmlDocument();
                childDoc.LoadXml(childTransaction);
                doclist = GetAcordDocuments(document, roles, errors, releaseID);
                foreach(Document doc in doclist)
                {
                    docEntireList.Add(doc);
                }

            }
```

I do not want to use loop and two lists to concatenate the result from the loop. I tried to use lambda and Linq like :

```
   List<Document> docs  = 
   XDocument.Load(transactionXML).Descendants("Transaction").SelectMany(child => 
   {
        var childDoc = new XmlDocument();
        childDoc.LoadXml(child.ToString());
        return GetAcordDocuments(childDoc, roles, errors, releaseID);
   });
```

This gives error as cannot implicitly convert type "System.Collections.Generic IE numerable<> to  "System.Collections.Generic.List<> . I wonder why, because the code with loop does not give the type cast error. The return type of function is as List of  Document type.

```
  private static List<Document> GetAcordDocuments(XmlDocument,..)
```

Thanks , please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectMany` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.  You need to call `ToList` on the result:

```
   List<Document> docs  = 
   XDocument.Load(transactionXML).Descendants("Transaction").SelectMany(child => 
   {
        var childDoc = new XmlDocument();
        childDoc.LoadXml(child.ToString());
        return GetAcordDocuments(childDoc, roles, errors, releaseID);
   }).ToList();
```

It works in the `foreach` loop because you're adding items to an existing list.

Comment: Would rather change the signature to `IEnumerable` than casting the `IEnumerable` to `List`.

Comment: @Mephy That depends on the usage afterwards.

Comment: This is an existing project and is used all over so signature can not be changed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the return type of `GetAcordDocuments` returns a `List`, but that's not what you're assigning to `docs`. You're assigning the result of `SelectMany` to `docs`, and `SelectMany` returns an `IEnumerable`, not an `IList`.  Either type `docs` as an `IEnumerable`, or materialize the query into a `List`.

Additionally, rather than converting each child element into a string only to parse that string into a new document, you would be better off simply passing the actual child element (that you've already taken the time to parse) directly into the method in question.